# email BCC limit

Tags: apex, visualforce, email

I am sending out emails via APEX code. SO far I am facing exceptions when the bcc characters are around 500 - 550 characters  or more, and the number of bcc email addresses is around 21 - 25 or more.

I work on enterprise edition. Is this the standard Salesforce limit?

Is there any workaround ?

Will these limits be surpassed if I use batch apex ?(I dont think so)

Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

For [Single Email Messaging](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_classes_outbound_single) using the `setBccAddresses` method, the limit is 25 email addresses. That method isn't supported by the Mass Email Message Class.